# Is there a way to redirect a path in apache2 to another virtual host

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

I have several virtual hosts running on one machine, and I would like to override one path from one virtual host onto another.  My original plan was to use mod rewrite, but I got stuck on the absolute URL.

I would like the following behavior, (without using 301 redirects.):

```
http://sub1.example.com/sub2 -> sub2.example.com virtual host
# Everything but sub2/.*
http://sub1.example.com/     -> sub1.example.com virtual host
http://sub2.example.com/     -> sub2.example.com virtual host
```

I was testing this out with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Directory /var/lib/wsgi>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
   </Directory>

   ServerName sub1.example.com
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/lib/wsgi/sub1.wsgi
   WSGIDaemonProcess sub1 display-name=%{GROUP}
   WSGIProcessGroup sub1

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/sub2/(.*)$ http://sub2.example.com/sub2/$1 [PT]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Directory /var/lib/wsgi>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
   </Directory>

   ServerName sub2.example.com
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/lib/wsgi/sub2.wsgi
   WSGIDaemonProcess sub2 display-name=%{GROUP}
   WSGIProcessGroup sub2
</VirtualHost>
```

I am running a Python WSGI application in each subdomain.  When you  access http://sub1.example.com/sub2 apache2 returns "400 Bad Request" and puts this in the log file.

```
[Fri Jul 08 16:09:05 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Invalid URI in request GET /sub2/ HTTP/1.1
```

I have also tried using [ServerPath](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serverpath) inside of the sub2 domain, but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing any url modification/fancy matching, why not try

```
<VirtualHost ...>
    // sub1 site
    Redirect /sub2 http://sub2.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

mod_rewrite is heavy artillery when all you really need is a pea shooter.

That, or use an alias:

```
Alias /sub2   /full/path/to/equivalent/directory/in/sub2
```

Comment: Redirect would send the client to another site.  I would like to hide the sub2 virtual host from clients that are accessing the site from sub1.  Alias only works for paths that are on disk, and it doesn't let you modify the hostname.

Comment: Then use the alias, it'll make the sub2 site's content available under /sub2 in the sub1 site.

Comment: From what I have read, you cannot use Alias to direct traffic to another Virtual Host.  This would work if sub2 was serving static files, but it is running a WSGI script.

Comment: Aliases don't redirect traffic. They're effective a symlink within apache, making the aliased directory appear as part of the site, even though it can be pointing at a directory completely outside of the webroot.